# Not able to set value of a dictionary inside a array [Swift]

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to set the value of a dictionary inside a array in swift but I get an error. 

It says `Cannot pass immutable value of type '[Dictionary]' to mutating binary operator '+='`

My code is the following:

`// Declare the array
    var numbersArray:[Dictionary] = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()`


... more code ...

```
func createArray() {
    for var iteration = 0; iteration < 75; iteration++ {
        //Add numbers to the array
        // May be used to set column
        var column:String
        switch iteration {
        case 0...14:
            column = "B"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "B", "Origin" : 0]]
        case 15...29:
            column = "I"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "I", "Origin" : 0]]
        case 30...44:
            column = "N"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "N", "Origin" : 0]]
        case 45...59:
            column = "G"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "G", "Origin" : 0]]
        case 60...74:
            column = "O"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "O", "Origin" : 0]]
        default:
            column = "Out Of Bounds"
            numbersArray += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "Out Of Bounds", "Origin" : 0]]
        }
        // numbersArray1 += [["Randomized" : false, "Column" : String(column), "Origin" : 0]]

    }
}
```

Any Idea? 
**Note:** This worked perfectly in the playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems.

First of all, you declare numbersArray to be an array of generic dictionaries, which is something that makes my XCode to crash.  The following approach works better for me:

```
var numbersArray = [[String: Any]]()
```

Secondly, I guess createArray is a method in a `struct`, in which case you have to use `mutating` in its declaration to allow it to modify `struct`'s properties.

```
mutating func createArray() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The first correction solved it all, the second on wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use += for arrays of not compatible items (where the type can change), you need append the value to the array like so:

```
var numbersArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() 
numbersArray.append(["Randomized" : false, "Column" : "B", "Origin" : 0])
```

You would be able to use += if you had an array of Strings or Int's

```
var numbersArray = [String]() 
NumbersArray += ["I am always a string"]
```

More details about collections at [this apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: What exactly does it mean by "incompatible"?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, the code in question works perfectly in playground.

Comment: @DavidLiu playground has its bugs, I also explain it a little further, you can also check the details about this issue in the apple documentation above.